# Joint density of $X$ and $g(X,Y)$

Tags: probability, integration, conditional-expectation, stochastic-integrals, density-function

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables and $g$ be a measurable function. Assumed that it exists what is the joined density of $X$ and $g(X,Y)$?
I have tried to derive it with $P(X\in A,g(X,Y)\in B)$ but was not succesful.

Comment: The change of variable $$(z,t)=(x,g(x,y))$$ with Jacobian $$dzdt=g_y(x,y)dxdy$$ works like a charm, no?